# How to auto-create and chroot jail an anonymous user on an FTP server?

Tags: linux, ftp

I would like to know if it's possible to set-up a Linux FTP server to allow anonymous log-in, and also to place that anonymous user in a chroot jail whose root is somehow based on the anonymous log-in credentials.

For example, I would like to be able to tell someone to log-in to my FTP server with the credentials, username `anonymous` and password `xt66ach883a`, and for the server to automatically place that anonymous user in a chroot jail whose root is `/ftp/xt66ach883a`.

Additionally, if the intended chroot jail root folder does not exist, I would like to have it automatically created.

If anyone has achieved a similar set-up before, or could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful for your advice.

Comment: SFTP != FTP != FTPS -- make up your mind what you need. You can script anything and chroots (for SFTP) are supported in openSSH.

Comment: @Jakuje sorry, I didn't realise they weren't the same thing! Updating my question to relate to plain-old FTP.

Comment: And in any case having the chrooted user's "FTP home" with the same name as the user's FTP password is a very bad idea in terms of security.

Comment: @snoopy91 will you have different user names (other than `anonymous`) with different passwords, or _just_ user `anonymous`, with different passwords -- and each different password will have its own home directory?